# Angular 7 application is not working fine in IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, routes

Application is working fine in local envirmonment in all the browser(including IE 11).

But after deployemnt it is not loading the main page in IE except it is navigating to default error page. It is happening
only in IE 11.

Only thing which I noticed that IE is removing trailing slash in the deployed version.

http://localhost:4200/ - works fine in IE but http://myapplication.com/main/ is not working in IE, it is showing the error page.

**App routing module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', loadChildren: './modules/customer/customer.module#CustomerModule'},
  {path: '**', component: ErrorpageComponent, data: {name: 'noMatch'}},
];
```

**Customer module**

```
const customerRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: CustomerComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', component: OnboardingComponent},
      {path: '**', component: ErrorpageComponent, data: {name: 'noMatch'}}
    ]
  }
];
```

In IE after deployment it always redires to `ErrorPageComponent`. While running in local it is working fine in IE as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit**

I forgot to mention that "myapplication.com/main/" gets added from nginx (server side). Client side we are not adding `main`.

I tried by running application in prod mode as well `ng serve --prod`, and it is working fine in IE. After deploy to Dev it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue and fixed, sharing here as it may help others.
I have added relative path in app.module and it started working in IE.

**Appmodule**

```
export function getBaseHref(): string {
  return window.location.pathname;
}
```

....

```
providers: [{
  provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
  useFactory: getBaseHref,
}],
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you like to see the `OnboardingComponent` if you navigate to `myapplication.com/main/`. In this case you should add `main` to the path of your `OnboardingComponent`.

```
 {path: 'main', component: OnboardingComponent},
```

Of course you will have to use this in your local environemnt also with `localhost:4200/main/`.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that "myapplication.com/main/" is adding from nginx (server side). client side we are not adding main

Comment: Ah ok. Other browsers work? It is realy only IE that can't handle the deployed version? And if so, what exactly do you mean by _IE is removing trailing slash_

Comment: Yes only in IE it is happening. Only difference I can see IE is removing trailing slash. Not sure is that is the cause.

Comment: You mean ` http://myapplication.com/main` (IE) instead of ` http://myapplication.com/main//` (other browsers)?

Comment: yes in IE : -myapplication.com/main other browse myapplication.com/main/

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour with IE11. Probably a problem with a configuration detail of your server.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include the IE polyfills. These can be found in src/polyfills.ts and you can uncomment the following:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/   
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';   
import 'core-js/es6/object';   
import 'core-js/es6/function';   
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';   
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';   
import 'core-js/es6/number';   
import 'core-js/es6/math';   
import 'core-js/es6/string';   
import 'core-js/es6/date';   
import 'core-js/es6/array';   
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';  
import 'core-js/es6/map';  
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';  
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```